# Text hidden with filldraw in circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I'm trying to learn Tikz and I'm running into some problems with the filldraw methods, circle and text.
I want to have a ellipse in the background, with a circle on top, with a text inside the circle.

I can have the circle + text, or ellipse + circle but with the text hidden somehow. The code below is as far as I got, and it seems to be invalid, but I can't find why..

Any help is most welcomed !

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (0,0) node {Lvl1};

\newcount\myX
\foreach \id [count=\x from 0] in {{00},{01},{10},{11}}
    \myX = \numexpr(3 + \x * 2)\relax;
    % the ellipse code
    \filldraw[fill=gray!20!white, thick] (\myX,0) circle [x radius=0.9, y radius=0.7];
    % the circle code
    \draw [thick,black] (\myX,0) circle [radius=0.5] node {\id};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of commands in `\foreach` loop is greater than 1, you need a pair of `{` and `}` (like in C/C++ and many other programming languages). In your original code, only

```
\myX = \numexpr(3 + \x * 2)\relax;
```

is recognized as inside the loop, hence the compilation error.

Adding `{` and `}`, you will have what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (0,0) node {Lvl1};

\newcount\myX
\foreach \id [count=\x from 0] in {00,01,10,11} {
    \myX = \numexpr(3 + \x * 2)\relax;
    % the ellipse code
    \filldraw[fill=gray!20!white, thick] (\myX,0) circle [x radius=0.9, y radius=0.7];
    % the circle code
    \draw [thick,black] (\myX,0) circle [radius=0.5] node {\id};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lol. Thanks for spotting this, I need to spend more time learning the turing complete language that is Latex...